# Regex: Match everything, but a new empty line

Tags: php, regex

How do I match every character but two consecutive newline characters, `\n\n` ?

Obviously `([^\n\n]+?)` doesn't work, since that every `\n` is treated individually.

Comment: can try `([^/\n]+?)`

Comment: That matches everything but a single newline character just fine. I'm looking to match everything but an empty line :)

Comment: empty line .you can try `^$` with `m` flag on

Comment: An example would be better to clarify your question.

Comment: Consider perhaps removing the question mark in order to get full length strings `([^\n\n]+)` with a g global flag : 
`/([^\n\n]+)/g`

see example : http://regex101.com/r/hO9hA8/17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: `([^\n]+\n)*[^\n]+`

(http://regex101.com/r/lP2uB9/1)